# jQuery Related (Dependent) Selects Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, select

I found [this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-related-dependent-selects-plugin/) jquery plugin for dependent select box . This worked now but i have big problem ! when put this in submit form not worked because this plugin worked with form id and post/get data using json. Original Demo [HERE](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-related-selects/)

Problem e.x:

```
<div id="box">
   <form action="search.php" method="POST" >
   <form id="example-1">
   <div class="field">

   <label for="name">state :</label>

    <select name="stateID">

    <option value="">Choose State &raquo;</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="name">Country :</label>
    <select name="countyID">
    <option value="">Choose County &raquo;</option>

    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="name">town :</label>
    <select name="townID">
    <option value="">Choose Town &raquo;</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="name">village :</label>
    <select name="villageID">
    <option value="">Choose Village &raquo;</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
</form>
</div>
```

If I Remove form action this plugin worked perfectly, Otherwise not worked. How To Fix This Thanks.

Comment: You have a random <form> tag inside of your <form> just floating around out there. Remove that <form id="example-1"> tag. Instead of using div class='field', consider using the <fieldset> tag and styling it.

Comment: fieldset worked when all form in one div. i change my question! i have for each selectBox any div(class=field) and labal.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, you can capture the submit of the form and do with it what you like.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //stop the default behavior
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', //default is get, set to 'POST' if you want to post.
    url: 'search.php',
    success: function(data){
      //if our data was returned from our search file as json, then...
      $("#element").html(data.a) //returns the a value from our json object
      $("#element").html(data.b) //returns the b value from our json object
      //etc
    }
  });
});
```

The submit function stops the form from submitting per the usual fashion, and stops the page-reload. Then we use an ajax request to send our data through the 'POST' method to our file search.php. The returned data is sent in an object, and we access it through our success:function(data). Then, if our data was returned with JSON values, we can use data.a to get the a value, or data.b to get the b value of our JSON string.